I'm beyond stuck trying to create a compilation workflow for a python tkinter c binding that gives me a resize event my builds just keep failing
No matter how I have set up my environment so far to run the setup.py script I keep running into issues with environments, shells, ENV_Variables, and github workflow environment variables that seemingly don't point to the setup file.
Current .yml workflow state
name: Build and Save Wheels

on:
workflow_dispatch:
push:
branches-ignore:
- build  # Prevent workflow from running when pushing to the build branch

permissions:
contents: write  # Allows the workflow to push changes to the repository

jobs:
build_wheels:
name: Build Wheels for ${{ matrix.os }} on Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
strategy:
matrix:
os: \[ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, windows-latest\]
python-version: \['3.12'\]
architecture: \['x64'\]

    steps:
      - name: Check out the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      # - name: Cache MSYS2 (Windows only)
      #   if: matrix.os == 'windows-latest'
      #   uses: actions/cache@v3
      #   with:
      #     path: C:/msys64
      #     key: ${{ runner.os }}-msys2-${{ hashFiles('setup.py') }}  # You can use a different file for the hash
      #     restore-keys: |
      #       ${{ runner.os }}-msys2-
    
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
          architecture: ${{ matrix.architecture }}
    
      - name: Install dependencies for Linux/Mac
        if: matrix.os != 'windows-latest' && !steps.cache-msys2.outputs.cache-hit
        run: |
          if [[ ${{ matrix.os }} == 'ubuntu-latest' ]]; then
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install -y tk-dev tcl-dev libx11-dev
          elif [[ ${{ matrix.os }} == 'macos-latest' ]]; then
            brew install xquartz  # Install XQuartz to get X11 libraries
            export LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/X11/lib"  # Ensure X11 libraries are correctly linked
          fi
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
    
      - name: Install MSYS2 and Tcl/Tk for Windows
        if: matrix.os == 'windows-latest'
        run: |
          # Install MSYS2
          choco install msys2
          
          # Update MSYS2 and install necessary packages
          C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash -lc "pacman -Syu --noconfirm"
          C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash -lc "pacman -S --noconfirm mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-python3 mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-pip mingw-w64-x86_64-tcl mingw-w64-x86_64-tk"
    
      - name: Add MSYS2 Paths
        if: matrix.os == 'windows-latest'
        run: |
          # Add MSYS2 paths for Tcl/Tk and GCC to the GitHub runner's PATH
          echo "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
          echo "C:\msys64\mingw64\include" >> $GITHUB_PATH
          echo "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib" >> $GITHUB_PATH
    
      # - name: Build wheel in MinGW64 environment
      #   if: matrix.os == 'windows-latest'
      #   run: |
      #     # Use Python3 from MSYS2 environment for building the wheel
      #     C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash -lc "
      #     pacman -S python
      #     export Path="/usr/bin/python3:$PATH"
      #     export CC=gcc;
      #     export CXX=g++;
      #     export LDSHARED='\$CC -shared';
      #     export AR=ar;
      #     export RANLIB=ranlib;
      #     cd /c/$(echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE | sed 's/\\/\//g');  # Navigate to the correct workspace directory
      #     export PATH=/mingw64/bin:$PATH;
      #     python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel;
      #     python3 setup.py build;
      #     python3 setup.py bdist_wheel;
      #     "
      #     # C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash -lc "
      #     # cd /c/$(echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE | sed 's/\\/\//g');  # Ensure the MSYS2 shell is in the correct workspace directory
      #     # export PATH=/mingw64/bin:$PATH;  # Add MinGW64 paths to environment
      #     # python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel;
      #     # python3 setup.py build;  # Build the project
      #     # python3 setup.py bdist_wheel;  # Create the wheel package
      #     # "
    
      - name: Build Python Package
        if: matrix.os == 'windows-latest'
        run: |
          # Convert the Windows GitHub workspace path to a MSYS2-compatible path
          GITHUB_WORKSPACE_MSYS="/c$(echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE | cut -c 3- | sed 's/\\/\//g')"
    
          # Run the build in the MinGW64 shell
          C:/msys64/usr/bin/bash -lc "
          pacman -S --noconfirm python
          export PATH=/mingw64/bin:$PATH;
          export CC=gcc;
          export CXX=g++;
          export LDSHARED='\$CC -shared';
          export AR=ar;
          export RANLIB=ranlib;
    
          # Navigate to the correct workspace directory in MSYS2 format
          cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE_MSYS;
    
          # Ensure we have the latest pip and build tools
          python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel;
    
          # Build the project and create the wheel
          python3 setup.py build;
          python3 setup.py bdist_wheel;
          "
        shell: msys2
    
      - name: Move Windows build artifacts to dist
        if: matrix.os == 'windows-latest'
        run: |
          # Move the generated wheels to the dist/ directory in the GitHub workspace
          mv $GITHUB_WORKSPACE_MSYS/dist/*.whl ./dist/
    
      - name: Build wheel
        if: matrix.os != 'windows-latest'
        run: |
          python setup.py build
          python setup.py bdist_wheel  # Build the wheel
        shell: bash  # Use bash shell for this step
    
      - name: Commit and push the built wheels
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
          git config --global user.email "actions@github.com"
          
          git clean -fd  # Remove untracked files (such as wheel files in 'dist/')
          git checkout master
          git pull origin master  # Pull the latest changes from master
          python setup.py bdist_wheel  # Generate the wheel files
          git add .  # Add all changes to the commit
          git commit -a -m "Update wheel files for Python 3.12 on ${{ matrix.os }} (x64)"
          git push --force origin master  # Force push to overwrite the existing master branch
    
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

Most Recent Run
0s
Run # Convert the Windows GitHub workspace path to a MSYS2-compatible path

# Convert the Windows GitHub workspace path to a MSYS2-compatible path

GITHUB_WORKSPACE_MSYS="/c$(echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE | cut -c 3- | sed 's/\\///g')"

# Run the build in the MinGW64 shell

C:/msys64/usr/bin/bash -lc "
pacman -S --noconfirm python
export PATH=/mingw64/bin:$PATH;
export CC=gcc;
export CXX=g++;
export LDSHARED='$CC -shared';
export AR=ar;
export RANLIB=ranlib;

# Navigate to the correct workspace directory in MSYS2 format

cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE_MSYS;

# Ensure we have the latest pip and build tools

python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel;

# Build the project and create the wheel

python3 setup.py build;
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel;
"
Error: msys2: command not found

0s
Run # Convert the Windows GitHub workspace path to a MSYS2-compatible path

# Convert the Windows GitHub workspace path to a MSYS2-compatible path

GITHUB_WORKSPACE_MSYS="/c$(echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE | cut -c 3- | sed 's/\\///g')"

# Run the build in the MinGW64 shell

C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash -lc "
pacman -S --noconfirm python
export PATH=/mingw64/bin:$PATH;
export CC=gcc;
export CXX=g++;
export LDSHARED='$CC -shared';
export AR=ar;
export RANLIB=ranlib;

# Navigate to the correct workspace directory in MSYS2 format

cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE_MSYS;

# Ensure we have the latest pip and build tools

python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel;

# Build the project and create the wheel

python3 setup.py build;
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel;
"
shell: C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
env:
pythonLocation: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64/lib/pkgconfig
Python_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
Python2_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
Python3_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
GITHUB_WORKSPACE_MSYS=/c$(echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE | cut -c 3- | sed 's/\\///g'): D:\\a_temp\\f23a4ad5-d53d-453b-855d-8df1e85101bf.ps1:3
Line |
3 |  GITHUB_WORKSPACE_MSYS="/c$(echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE | cut -c 3- | sed ' …
|  \~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
| The module 'GITHUB_WORKSPACE_MSYS=/c$(echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE | cut -c 3- | sed 's/' could not be loaded. For
| more information, run 'Import-Module GITHUB_WORKSPACE_MSYS=/c$(echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE | cut -c 3- | sed 's/'.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Working Run that doesn't output file for windows and appears not to event be building it.
Run # Use Python3 from MSYS2 environment for building the wheel

# Use Python3 from MSYS2 environment for building the wheel

# C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash -lc "

# pacman -S python

# export Path="/usr/bin/python3:$PATH"

# export CC=gcc;

# export CXX=g++;

# export LDSHARED='$CC -shared';

# export AR=ar;

# export RANLIB=ranlib;

# cd /c/$(echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE | sed 's/\\///g');  # Navigate to the correct workspace directory

# export PATH=/mingw64/bin:$PATH;

# python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel;

# python3 setup.py build;

# python3 setup.py bdist_wheel;

# "

C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash -lc "
cd /c/$(echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE | sed 's/\\///g');  # Ensure the MSYS2 shell is in the correct workspace directory
export PATH=/mingw64/bin:$PATH;  # Add MinGW64 paths to environment
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel;
python3 setup.py build;  # Build the project
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel;  # Create the wheel package
"
shell: C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
env:
pythonLocation: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64/lib/pkgconfig
Python_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
Python2_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
Python3_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages (24.1.2)
Collecting pip
Downloading pip-24.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages (75.1.0)
Collecting wheel
Downloading wheel-0.44.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Downloading pip-24.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
\---------------------------------------- 1.8/1.8 MB 28.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading wheel-0.44.0-py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
\---------------------------------------- 67.1/67.1 kB 1.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: wheel, pip
Attempting uninstall: pip
Found existing installation: pip 24.1.2
Uninstalling pip-24.1.2:
Successfully uninstalled pip-24.1.2
Successfully installed pip-24.2 wheel-0.44.0
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python3.exe: can't open file 'C:/setup.py': \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python3.exe: can't open file 'C:/setup.py': \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.\`

\`Run # Add MSYS2 paths for Tcl/Tk and GCC to the GitHub runner's PATH

# Add MSYS2 paths for Tcl/Tk and GCC to the GitHub runner's PATH

echo "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin" \>\> $GITHUB_PATH
echo "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include" \>\> $GITHUB_PATH
echo "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib" \>\> $GITHUB_PATH
shell: C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
env:
pythonLocation: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64/lib/pkgconfig
Python_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
Python2_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
Python3_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64

0s
Run # Use Python3 from MSYS2 environment for building the wheel

# Use Python3 from MSYS2 environment for building the wheel

C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash -lc "
pacman -S python
export Path="/usr/bin/python3:$PATH"
export CC=gcc;
export CXX=g++;
export LDSHARED='$CC -shared';
export AR=ar;
export RANLIB=ranlib;
cd /c/$(echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE | sed 's/\\///g');  # Navigate to the correct workspace directory
export PATH=/mingw64/bin:$PATH;
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel;
python3 setup.py build;
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel;
"
shell: C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
env:
pythonLocation: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64/lib/pkgconfig
Python_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
Python2_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
Python3_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (2) mpdecimal-4.0.0-1  python-3.12.7-1

Total Download Size:    22.46 MiB
Total Installed Size:  182.13 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? \[Y/n\]
0s
2s
Run git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
git config --global user.email "actions@github.com"

git clean -fd  # Remove untracked files (such as wheel files in 'dist/')
git checkout master
git pull origin master  # Pull the latest changes from master
python setup.py bdist_wheel  # Generate the wheel files
git add .  # Add all changes to the commit
git commit -a -m "Update wheel files for Python 3.12 on windows-latest (x64)"
git push --force origin master  # Force push to overwrite the existing master branch
shell: C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
env:
pythonLocation: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64/lib/pkgconfig
Python_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
Python2_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
Python3_ROOT_DIR: C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.7\\x64
GITHUB_TOKEN: \*\*\*
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Already on 'master'
From https://github.com/FriendlyStepBro/py_TK_Custom_Events

* branch            master     -\> FETCH_HEAD
  5ef540f..53a96e9  master     -\> origin/master
  Updating 5ef540f..53a96e9
  Fast-forward
  .../resize_event.cpython-312-darwin.so              | Bin 67304 -\> 67304 bytes
  dist/resize_event-1.0-cp312-cp312-linux_x86_64.whl  | Bin 8676 -\> 8676 bytes
  ...vent-1.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_13_universal2.whl | Bin 4032 -\> 4032 bytes
  3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\\a\\py_TK_Custom_Events\\py_TK_Custom_Events\\setup.py", line 2, in \<module\>
  from setuptools import setup, Extension
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
  On branch master
  Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Everything up-to-date\`

The last one seemingly works, but when I look into the directory, I'm pushing it to the Windows binaries and metadata isn't there. I know its something stupid I'm not seeing but I'm just stuck.
Setup.py
import platform
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import os

# Detect the platform
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    source_file = 'win_Resize.c'
    
    # Use MSYS2 toolchain paths for GCC
    os.environ['CC'] = 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe'  # Use MSYS2 GCC compiler
    os.environ['CXX'] = 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe'  # Use MSYS2 G++
    os.environ['LD'] = 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/ld.exe'    # Use MSYS2 linker
    os.environ['AR'] = 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/ar.exe'    # Use MSYS2 archiver
    os.environ['RANLIB'] = 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/ranlib.exe'  # Use MSYS2 ranlib

    # Include and library paths for Tcl/Tk
    include_dirs = [
        'C:/msys64/mingw64/include'
    ]
    library_dirs = [
        'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib'
    ]
    libraries = ['tcl', 'tk']

elif platform.system() == 'Darwin':  # macOS
    source_file = 'unix_Resize.c'
    include_dirs = ['/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Headers', '/opt/X11/include']
    libraries = ['tcl', 'tk', 'X11']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/X11/lib']

else:  # Linux and others
    source_file = 'unix_Resize.c'
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/tcl', '/usr/include/tk', '/usr/include/X11']
    libraries = ['tcl', 'tk', 'X11']
    library_dirs = []

module = Extension(
    'resize_event',
    sources=[source_file],
    include_dirs=include_dirs,
    libraries=libraries,
    library_dirs=library_dirs
)

setup(
    name='resize_event',
    version='1.0',
    description='Custom Tkinter resize event',
    ext_modules=[module],
)

Is there a way to make this work so that I'm not dependent on runtime or configtime compiling of code for the system like using cmake.
